# Under-sampling leads to poor results for no apparent reason

Tags: python, random-forest, image-segmentation, imbalanced-data

I am using Random Forest for a semantic segmentation task, with 3 classes, which are imbalanced. First, I just trained the algorithms on random subsets containing 20% of all the pixels (else my memory cannot handle training the algorithms), and got IoU and Balanced accuracy scores of 0.83 and 0.91 on my test dataset (comprising 32 images representative of the dataset).
Then, to handle imbalance, I did this on the full training dataset (not the previous subset):

```
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state = 42)
X_resampled, Y_resampled = rus.fit_resample(X, Y)
```

leading to a training dataset with similar size to the previous one, but this time with balanced classes. But surprisingly, I notice that IoU and balanced accuracy are now equal to 0.78 and 0.84 on my test dataset.

Of course under-sampling can lead to bad performances, but generally it is because the under-sampled dataset is smaller than the original one. Here, the original one is already a subset.

Can someone tell me what could be the cause of these poor performances ?

Answer (score 0):

Your correct in the fact that under-sampling usually results in poor performance.

> Random undersampling deletes examples from the majority class and can result in losing information invaluable to a model.

Additionally, your model was trained on the imbalanced data, which could mean the model performs much better on the majority classes (because this constitutes a big portion of the loss). The new dataset has less of those samples for which the performance is better, so the model performs slightly worse.

However, your sample size is way too low to statistically represent the problem well. My guess is that with a bit of extra training on the augmented data, your model will perform just as well with the balanced data.

Comment: Yes, but in my case the dataset obtained after under-sampling contains as much - if not more - information as the dataset I used in the first place, because it is based on all the pixels and not just a subset. Having more information and more equal classes, I still find it surprising to have weaker performances.
Also, could you please elaborate on why my sample size is too low ? The task being a segmentation problem, each pixel is a training example, and I have millions of them.

Comment: While 32 images probably give a good first training estimate for the model, there are likely many aspects of the data left out in the first dataset. Did you train the model with the whole augmented dataset? If yes, then there could be many more factors affecting performance, most importantly the input data being different. If no, then the model is optimized for a different problem than the one at hand and thus performing worse.

Answer (score 0):

**Hypothesis 1:** Maybe you're just experiencing *variance* in your model: that is by changing training data, the performance of your model are changing too and by a large margin.

This can be due to the nature of the data, as well the model you're using. To confirm that try to do at least ten training with different random seeds. Then, aggregate the performance and compute the mean as well standard deviation of both IoU and accuracy. The std provides you the variance of your model: the lower the std, the lower the variability is. Well, you can also approximate that with K-fold cross-validation of just one training run.

**Hypothesis 2:** when you under-sample the problem can became either simpler or more difficult. If simpler maybe you're are overfitting so regularize the model more (check your training and validation metrics). Conversely if harder, you're underfitting: this may explain the lower performance, if so increase the model complexity or train for more.